# SQL with JOIN where column of one table is null if global WHERE is not fullfilled

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, left-join

it's been quite a while since I had to write SQL for the last time. I'm struggling with a select and I was hoping you can point out what I am missing.

I have a rather simple table structure with 2 tables:

1. Users

   - user_id
   - name
2. Estimates

   - user_id
   - estimate
   - estimation_date

The goal is to use a start and end date to show all estimations of all users. For users who don't have an estimate for that particular time range, I want the SQL to return me a null value.

In reality there are a few more tables and columns involved as well as some user role stuff but that is not necessary for this example.

I tried to setup my select like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.estimate, b.estimation_date
FROM users a
LEFT OUTER JOIN estimates b on a.id = b.id
WHERE b.estimation_date BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate OR b.estimation_date IS NULL
```

As long as a user has not made any estimate at all, the result is what I want. Each row is a user, same user can occur multiple times - once for each estimate in the date range - and a user without an estimate has NULL in b.estimate and b.estimation_date.

However, as soon as a user has made an estimation, even if it is not inside the range, the user does not show up in the result anymore.

What would be the best solution to input a start and end date and get all users and for each user who has no estimation inside this range get a NULL in those columns?

Comment: Not sure if there is a more efficient way to do this in "one query", but have you considered doing a subquery against the estimates table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the date range condition in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, e.estimate, e.estimation_date
FROM users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     estimates e
     ON u.id = e.id AND
        e.estimation_date >= $startdate AND
        (e.estimation_date <= $enddate OR e.estimation_date IS NULL)
```

Note that I also fixed the table aliases so they are not meaningless letters, but are abbreviations for the table name.